# Validate Username and Password separately in PHP ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a Login Form. as below:

```
<form id="myform"  method="POST" class="form_statusinput">
   <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" 
      placeholder="Enter email" data-original-title="" title="" 
      onblur="checkEmail()">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" 
       placeholder="Password" data-original-title="" title="" 
       onblur="checkPass()">
     </div>
</form>
```

I am validating Username and Password via Ajax on submitting the Form

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  validate();
  });
});
```

In `Validate` function, validations are done properly for empty or invalid characters but i want to return error to user that password is wrong or username is wrong.

Ajax call is as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/fo_submit",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg == 1) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $("#messagesuccerr").html("Wrong Credentails")
            .fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

`fo_submit` having PHP Databse connection and code

```
$query = "select * from `register_userfm` where `userchkname_yt` = ? 
and passchk_ty = ?; ";
$result = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute(array($_POST['email'],
$_POST['password']))->fetchAll();
if(count($resultfm1)>0){
    echo 1;
}
else{
    echo 0;
}
```

This way only error returned is "Invalid Credentials". Please let me know how to validate Username and Password separately.

Comment: you shouldn't validate them separately, it gives valuable information to potential attacker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use status codes returning them from the PHP script by running 2 different queries. Something like the following:

```
$query = "select * from `register_userfm` where `userchkname_yt` = ? and passchk_ty = ?; ";
$result = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute(array($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))->fetchAll();
if(count($result)>0){
    echo "1"; //auth success
}
else{
    $query = "select * from `register_userfm` where `userchkname_yt` = ?;";
    $result = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute(array($_POST['email']))->fetchAll();
    if(count($result)>0){
        echo -1; //password wrong
    }
    else{
        echo 0; //username wrong
    }
}
```

You can then check the returned value in the ajax callback and act accordingly.

**word of advice**: Giving a possible attacker this information (what he got wrong) makes it possible to highly lower the time needed for a bruteforce/dictionary attack

Comment: Yeah.. that i got.. Nice Suggestion... Now if i want to Give user the facility to find Order Status taking input as Order ID and Phone numbe r then will it be good to display Order ID wrong or Ph num Wrong

Comment: If it's after the auth and they can load just their orders yeah

Comment: Then same as above. In every case you are providing a way to access sensitive information to someone with multiple inputs you should refrain from giving said person a way to know what value he got wrong

Comment: ohkies.. thats fine.. Thanks